# How to create backup copy of a table including table contents

Tags: mysql, sql, copy, backup

I'm having problems creating a backup copy of one of my tables (I wish to back up all the contents as well).

I tried this

```
SELECT *
INTO Copy_customers
FROM Customers;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Answer (score 0):

To take backup of single table you can use dump command as follows:
**Dump and restore a single table from .sql**
Dump

```
mysqldump db_name table_name > table_name.sql
```

Dumping from a remote database

```
mysqldump -u<db_username> -h<db_host> -p<db_password> db_name table_name > table_name.sql
```

Restore

```
mysql -u username -p db_name < /path/to/table_name.sql
```

Comment: is their not an sql command i can use to make a backup of table and contents ?

Comment: @Jmac88, It depends upon what version of mysql you are using. If you are using version earlier than 5.5 then you can use **BACKUP TABLE** command which is deprecated in since MySql 5.5. There are only two options only since then **mysqldump** and **mysqlhotcopy**. Most popular and recommended is Mysqldump.